# Javascript GET request before window.open prevents target _blank

Tags: javascript

I want to make a click recorder in javascript and then open the requested link in a new tab. Pretty much the same that happens when you click a google search result.

This code is supposed to do it and it almost does it. The only thing is that the window.open is not going to open a new tab. Instead it opens the page in the same tab. If I remove the xmlhttp call from the code then the '_blank' is respected. Why the xmlhttp request before the window.open is preventing the '_blank' to take effect?

```
recordClick = function(t, id) {
  var clickurl = "http://www.example.com";
  if(clickurl != undefined && clickurl.length > 0) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET",clickurl,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  if(id > 0) {
    window.open("http://www.example.com/click/"+id, '_blank');
  } else {
    window.open(t, '_blank');
  }
}
```

UPDATE

This was easy. Adding `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Using **JavaScript** instead of target to open new windows:

```
/*
 * Create the new window
 */


function openInNewWindow() {
    // Change "_blank" to something like "newWindow" to load all links in the same new window

    var newWindow = window.open(this.getAttribute('href'), '_blank');
    newWindow.focus();
    return false;
}

/*
 * Add the **openInNewWindow** function to the **onclick** event of links with a class name of "non-html"
 */

function getNewWindowLinks() {
    if (document.getElementById && document.createElement && document.appendChild) {
        var strNewWindowAlert = " (opens in a new window)";
        var objWarningText;
        var strWarningText;
        var link;
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                link = links[i];
                // Find all links with a class name of "non-html"
                if (/\bnon\-html\b/.exec(link.className)) {
                    // Create an em element containing the new window warning text and insert it after the link text
                    objWarningText = document.createElement("em");
                    strWarningText =     document.createTextNode(strNewWindowAlert);
                    objWarningText.appendChild(strWarningText);
                    link.appendChild(objWarningText);
                    link.onclick = openInNewWindow;
                  }
        }
    objWarningText = null;
   }
}
```